# Matplotlib graph embedded into tkinter window has a strange gray "bar" at the top

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I've created a matplotlib bar chart to show averages in the current month of preciptation, high and low temperature. I've stored the matplotlib code in a separate module like so, because of the amount of modules you have to import to transclude it into a tkinter window, like so:

```
from functions import Statistics

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

from tkinter import *

class Plot:
    def __init__(self, key, zipcode, tk):
        self.tk = tk
        self.tk.wm_title('Weather')
        stats = Statistics(zipcode, key)
        self.f = Figure(figsize=(6, 6))
        self.a = self.f.add_subplot(111)
        self.t = ('Precip (In.)', 'High (F)', 'Low (F)')
        self.tt = np.arange(len(self.t))
        self.s = [float(stats.avg_precip), float(stats.avg_high), float(stats.avg_low)]

        self.a.bar(self.tt, self.s, color = 'red', align='center')
        self.a.set_title(stats.title)
        self.a.set_xticklabels(self.t)
        self.a.set_xticks(self.tt)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f, master=self.tk)

    def show(self):
        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
```

I have tested the class and functions in a separate script here:

```
from plot import Plot
from data import Data
data = Data()

from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()

plt = Plot(data.api_key3, '57064', tk)

plt.show()
```

[It works exactly as I want it to.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4y87A.png)

**However!**

When I attempt to implement it into the main script;

```
def stats(key, zipcode):
    unpack()
    plot = Plot(key, zipcode, tk) 
    plot.show()
```

Executed by the press of this button;

```
btn_3 = Button(tk, text="Statistics", command = lambda: stats(data.api_key3, ent.get()))
```

It DOES display the graph, [but there is now a very ugly gray "bar" at the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6al0z.png)

Here is the full main script:

```
import logging
LOG_FILENAME='error_log.log'
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME, level=logging.DEBUG)

logging.debug('WeatherLog')

from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
tk.resizable(0,0)

import tkinter.messagebox

from img import *
img = Images()

from data import Data
data = Data()

from functions import Current_weather, Alerts, Forecast

from plot import Plot

canvas = Canvas(tk, width=275, height=100)
tk.wm_iconbitmap("cloud.ico")
tk.title("Weather")
canvas.pack()

lbl = Label(tk, text="Enter Zip Code")

ent = Entry(tk)

def pack():
    lbl.place(x=100, y=12)
    ent.place(x=80, y=40)
    btn.place(anchor=CENTER, height=25, width = 65, x = 140, y = 85)
    btn_2.place(anchor=CENTER, height=25, width = 65, x = 45, y = 85)
    btn_3.place(anchor=CENTER, height=25, width=65, x=235, y=85)

def unpack():
    lbl.place_forget()
    ent.place_forget()
    btn.place_forget()
    btn_2.place_forget()
    btn_3.place_forget()

def about():
    logo = Logo()

    toplevel = Toplevel(width=300, height=165)
    toplevel.resizable(0,0)
    toplevel.wm_iconbitmap("cloud.ico")
    toplevel.title("About this program...")

    about_text = Label(toplevel, text="Created by Michelle")
    about_text2 = Label(toplevel, text="Special thanks to all the folks on the freenode network")
    about_text3 = Label(toplevel, text="API provided by:")
    blankspace = Label(toplevel, text="                 ")

    logo_image = Label(toplevel, image = logo.logo)
    logo_image.image = logo.logo

    about_text.pack()
    about_text2.pack()
    about_text3.pack()
    blankspace.pack()
    logo_image.pack()

def stats(key, zipcode):
    unpack()
    plot = Plot(key, zipcode, tk) 
    plot.show()

def return_2_form2():
    for x in range(4):
        canvas.delete("img%s" % x)

    for x in range(12):
        canvas.delete("line%s" % x)

    for x in range(3):
        canvas.delete("br%s" % x)

    canvas.delete("title")
    canvas.config(width=275, height=100, background=data.default_color)
    goback_button2.pack_forget()
    pack()

def forecast(key, zipcode):
    try:
        forecast = Forecast(key, zipcode)
        current_weather = Current_weather(key, zipcode)
        unpack()

        if data.hour >= 15 or data.hour <= 6:
            bg = data.night_color
            weather_icon = img.weather_icon_night
            text_color = data.night_text_color
        elif data.hour <= 16 or data.hour >= 7:
            bg = data.day_color
            weather_icon = img.weather_icon_day
            text_color = data.day_text_color

        canvas.config(width=350, height=475, background=bg)

        canvas.create_text(175, 15, text= "Forecast for %s, %s" % (current_weather.city, current_weather.state), font=('Fixedsys', 12), fill=text_color , tag="title")

        for x in range(4): 
            canvas.create_image(25, 75+100*x, anchor=NW, image=weather_icon[forecast.days[x].conditions], tag="img%s" % x)
            canvas.create_text(50, 65+100*x, text="%s" % forecast.days[x].weekday, font=('Fixedsys', 6), fill=text_color, tag="line%s" % x)
            canvas.create_text(225, 70+100*x, text="%s" % forecast.days[x].conditions, font=('Fixedsys', 6), fill=text_color, tag="line%s" % str(x+1))
            canvas.create_text(225, 90+100*x, text="High: %s , Low: %s" % (forecast.days[x].high, forecast.days[x].low), font=('Fixedsys', 6), fill=text_color, tag="line%s" % str(x+2))
            canvas.create_text(225, 110+100*x, text="Wind: %s %s" % (forecast.days[x].wind_speed, forecast.days[x].wind_direction), font=('Fixedsys', 6), fill=text_color, tag="line%s" % str(x+3))

        for x in range(3):
            canvas.create_line(35, 140+100*x, 315, 140+100*x, fill=text_color, tag="br%s" % x)

        goback_button2.pack()

    except:
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Something went wrong.", "Unable to fetch forecast. Either you entered an invalid zip code, or you've hit the maximum daily requests.")

        logging.exception('Unhandled exception:')
        raise

def return_2_form():
    canvas.config(width=275, height=100, background=data.default_color)

    canvas.delete("banner")
    canvas.delete("alert")
    canvas.delete("img")

    for x in range(1, 6):
        canvas.delete("line%s" % x)
        goback_button.pack_forget()
        pack()

def current_weather(key, zipcode):
    try:
        current_weather = Current_weather(key, zipcode)
        alerts = Alerts(key, zipcode)
        unpack()

        bg = None
        weather_icon = None
        text_color = None

        if data.hour >= 15 or data.hour <= 6:
            bg = data.night_color
            weather_icon = img.weather_icon_night
            text_color = data.night_text_color
        elif data.hour <= 16 or data.hour >= 7:
            bg = data.day_color
            weather_icon = img.weather_icon_day
            text_color = data.day_text_color

        if alerts.check_alerts():
            canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 552, 30, fill = '#FF5D00', tag="banner")
            canvas.create_text(275, 15, text= "%s Effective until %s" % (alerts.description, alerts.expires), font=('Fixedsys', 10), tag="alert")
            canvas.config(width=550, height=225, background=bg)

        else:
            canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 552, 30, fill = '#FF5D00', tag="banner")
            canvas.create_text(275, 15, text= "No Alerts Active", font=('Fixedsys', 10), tag="alert")
            canvas.config(width=550, height=225, background=bg)


        canvas.create_image(25, 70, anchor=NW, image=weather_icon[current_weather.weather], tag="img")
        canvas.create_text(275, 80, text= "%s, %s" % (current_weather.city, current_weather.state), font=('Fixedsys', 18), fill=text_color, tag="line1")
        canvas.create_text(275, 145, text= "The weather is currently %s" % current_weather.weather, font=('Fixedsys', 16), fill=text_color, tag="line2")
        canvas.create_text(275, 160, text= "The temperature is %s" % current_weather.temperature_string, font=('Fixedsys', 16), fill=text_color, tag="line3")
        canvas.create_text(275, 175, text= "But, it feels like %s" % current_weather.feelslike_string, font=('Fixedsys', 16), fill=text_color, tag="line4")
        canvas.create_text(275, 190, text= "Wind is blowing %s" % current_weather.wind_string, font=('Fixedsys', 16), fill=text_color, tag="line5")

        goback_button.pack()

    except:
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Something went wrong.", "Unable to fetch weather conditions. Either you entered an invalid zip code, or you've hit the maximum daily requests.")

        logging.exception('Unhandled exception:')
        raise

menubar = Menu(tk)

helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
helpmenu.add_command(label="Help")
helpmenu.add_separator()
helpmenu.add_command(label="About", command=about)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)

tk.config(menu=menubar)

btn = Button(tk, text="Current", command = lambda: current_weather(data.api_key3, ent.get()))
btn_2 = Button(tk, text="Forecast", command = lambda: forecast(data.api_key3, ent.get()))
btn_3 = Button(tk, text="Statistics", command = lambda: stats(data.api_key3, ent.get()))

goback_button = Button(tk, text="Go back", command=return_2_form)
goback_button2 = Button(tk, text="Go back", command=return_2_form2)
goback_button3 = Button(tk, text='Go back',)

pack()
canvas.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The gray bar is the area occupied by the canvas, you unpacked the `lbl`, `ent`, `btn`, `btn_2`, and `btn_3` but did not unpack `canvas`. Add `canvas.pack_forget()` to the `unpack` function.

Also, it is not recommended to use multiple geometry managers in the same master/parent (You used `pack` on the canvas and `place` on the other widgets sharing `tk` as parent.